# problem with mediawiki cookies

Tags: cookies, mediawiki

anytime a user logs into our Wiki they get the following error: "This Wiki uses cookies to log in users. You have cookies disabled. Please enable them and try again." Even though the error displays, the user is actually logged in and can make edits as normal. If the user doesn't look closely they can't tell they are logged in and it's causing confusion I would be glad if anyone gives me a hint

Answer (score 12):

Wikimedia's advice is

> Check to make sure PHP's directory for storing session data is writable. This directory can be found in the `php.ini` file under the `session.save_path` setting. Errors in this `php.ini` setting can also cause other problems.

... (and) make sure the Internet Guest Account (eg. IUSR_FOOBAR, nobody, or apache) has write permissions to the folder listed in the `session.save_path` variable of the php.ini file.

[Source.](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Logging_in#Log_in_problems)

If you are using a hosting site you need to edit your php scripting configuration (php.ini).  The page should have information on your web document root.  If there is already a "tmp" folder created then use it.  If there is not a tmp folder in your current set up create one that is NOT browseable by users and tell the php.ini file the location as directed above.

Comment: This was my problem: "*... (and) make sure the Internet Guest Account (eg. IUSR_FOOBAR, nobody, or apache) has write permissions to the folder listed in the `session.save_path` variable of the php.ini file.*"

Answer (score 7):

For future reference... We just had a similar problem on Appropedia (same error, but couldn't log in at all). It turned out the temp directory was full. Cleared the temp directory, problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

> It turned out the temp directory was full

In my case it was because the entire partition was full, needed more space.

Answer (score 0):

Problem I just had was due to default install of our PHP using C:\windows\temp as a base folder for PHP session and other data.

Of course, once someone empties out the temp folder because its full of junk .... the sub-folders for PHP information go with it too :\

Answer (score -1):

If you are using NGINX + PHP-FPM the previous answers will likely not be of any assistance.

From the command line, run:

php-fpm -i|grep --color cookie_path

See what your cookie_path is, then stat the folder and ensure your php-fpm user has write access to it.

To resolve this issue using Nginx and Php-Fpm, I had to change my cookie_path from it's default of / (seriously, why would this be a default?) to /tmp.

After restarting nginx and php-fpm, it works perfectly.

Comment: I am using lighttpd and php-fpm and the other answers didn't work for me, but this answer has an error: session.cookie_path is the URL path of the session cookie, i. e. to which "part" of the website the session applies, not where on the file system the session server data is stored.

Comment: Instead of downvoting my comment because you're mad, did you want to post some information like the error you are getting? 

Sounds like you are using a URL instead of the unix path, so it sounds like the error is your fault, and has nothing to do with my explanation. The session path is definitely the unix path, and never a URL. The session has to live on the filesystem for there to ever be a session.

Comment: From PHP.net:
session.cookie_path string
session.cookie_path specifies path to set in the session cookie. Defaults to /. See also session_get_cookie_params() and session_set_cookie_params().

Comment: I am not mad, and I downvoted your answer because it is wrong.  Per http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-path, session.cookie_path does not refer to a file system directory, but a URL prefix.  session.save_path configures the path on the file system where session data is stored.

Comment: That's not what the document says at all. Why would it default to a location in the filesystem if it expected a URL?
"Defaults to /."
My above quote is quoting the reference you are posting.

It really doesn't matter, good luck with your issue.

Comment: I didn't say that it expected a URL, but a URL path or prefix.  Are you aware of the "Path" attribute of a "Set-Cookie" HTTP header?

Comment: The php.ini is a configuration file for the php service as it runs on the server. This ini doesn't control outbound headers, your webserver is responsible for this. 

You aren't directing the path of the browser's cookie by changing the ini. As far as I know, that's not a possibility unless you are using PHP code itself to send and manipulate headers. 

I also don't see the ini alluded to in the documentation for Set-Cookie:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: No, php.ini configures PHP.  Part of PHP is support for sessions (cf. http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php), either with a cookie or in the URL.  MediaWiki uses the former.  The (URL) path for the session cookie is determined by the configuration parameter session.cookie_path.

Comment: Good luck man. Its not worth arguing with you, we clearly don't agree.

Comment: You're more than invited to present a reproducible test case where you set session.cookie_path to a directory in the file system (different from session.save_path) and then something is written there.

Comment: I dont need your welcome, this worked for me already, that's why its posted. The fact is that it worked for me. The opinon is located above this comment ^