# MediaWiki - "You have cookies disabled"

Tags: php, mediawiki, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm currently running an instance of MediaWiki on Windows Server 2008 R2. At some point yesterday, it started giving us this error when trying to log in:

"Wiki uses cookies to log in users. You have cookies disabled. Please enable them and try again"

We, of course, have cookies enabled. I've tried every single thing I could from the various posts I've found about this, including these:

[MediaWiki sessions and cookies not working on multi-server behind CloudFlare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25317403/mediawiki-sessions-and-cookies-not-working-on-multi-server-behind-cloudflare)

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Thread:Project:Support_desk/Wiki_uses_cookies_to_log_in_users._You_have_cookies_disabled._Please_enable_them_and_try_again._Please_help_:(

[problem with mediawiki cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148583/problem-with-mediawiki-cookies)

[MediaWiki uses cookies to log in users. You have cookies disabled. Please enable them and try again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35379951/mediawiki-uses-cookies-to-log-in-users-you-have-cookies-disabled-please-enable)

[How can I fix the MediaWiki error "Wiki uses cookies to log in users. You have cookies disabled. Please enable them and try again."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16127882/how-can-i-fix-the-mediawiki-error-wiki-uses-cookies-to-log-in-users-you-have-c)

Nothing, so far, has worked. I'm running a [simple private wiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Preventing_access#Simple_private_wiki) setup, and I have a feeling this all started perhaps after the server rebooted or the IIS service got restarted.

Given that I've tried everything else that's mentioned in every thread I can find about this issue, what could be the root of the problem?

Comment: but do you actually get cookies from the page? From chrome you can click on the little icon on the left of the url to obtain some data about that page including the cookies

Comment: It does appear that the cookies are being received from the page. Confirmed that they're there, removed them and refreshed just to be sure, and they populated again.

Comment: could have something happened to the secure_cookie setting on your server? Are you using http or https? see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228262(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: Currently the wiki isn't using HTTPS, and nothing in the web config file mentions cookies.

Comment: This is either a problem with cookie handling (such as your web server filtering them out, or your browser not sending them back - see e.g. [T151770](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T151770)) or with your sessions (for MediaWiki 1.27+, see [$wgSessionCacheType](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgSessionCacheType) and [T138072](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T138072)).